# hadoop 3.1.2 ./start-all.sh error, syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I'm running hadoop 3.1.2 on mac, and when executing ./start-all.sh, I got error saying

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
```

I open the hadoop-functions.sh and find below info in line 398:

```
done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do
    echo "${text}"
  done | sort)
```

any idea how to fix that?

Comment: That looks like a bug.  How did you install Hadoop?

Comment: brew install hadoop @tk421

Comment: I think it a bug, I can start name node and data node separately, but couldn't use start-all.sh or start yarn @tk421

Comment: Yeah, I dug into the code base a bit and that has been there for a while.  It's a bash incompatibility where MacOS's bash version is 3.x while most Linuxes are running bash 4.x.

Comment: Looks like the ancient version of bash is due to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx.

Answer (score 2):

You found a bug although it's not likely to get resolved soon.  MacOS runs a bash 3.x but this syntax works on most modern Linuxes which run bash with a version 4.x.

According to the [Bash Manual:Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) `<(cmd(s)` gets treated as a file so you can interpret this as:

```
for text in "${input[@]}"; do
  echo "${text}"
done | sort > /tmp/results

while read -r line; do
  tmpa[${counter}]=${line}
  ((counter=counter+1))
  IFS='@' read -ra brup <<< "${line}"
  option="${brup[0]}"
  if [[ ${#option} -gt ${maxoptsize} ]]; then
    maxoptsize=${#option}
  fi
done < /tmp/results
```

Your options are:

- install a later version of bash
- rewrite the 2 instances of `< <(` in hadoop-functions.sh which are the only instances you'd hit of this construct.

#### References

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx
- [hadoop-functions.sh](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/hadoop-functions.sh#L390)